# Firebase Database Android - Retrieve Information Without ValueEventListeners

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have users on my Application and I store additional information about them in Firebase Database. I need to retrieve additional information in more than one Activity. I do not want to use ValueEventListeners because they are not called unless there is any change in the database. How can I get information about users from Database without using ValueEventListeners?

[image: Database view]

In my ProfileFragment I need to get name and departmant values.

I get current user from Firebase and I tried to take other information with a function.

```
 talker = new DatabaseTalk();
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
// Get info of logged in user with talker.
loggedInUser = talker.getUserFromID(currentUser.getUid());
```

This is my DatabaseTalker class to handle read and write operations to database

```
public class DatabaseTalk {
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference UserRef;
    private DatabaseReference SurveyRef;
    private List<User> userList;


    public DatabaseTalk(){
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        UserRef = mDatabase.getReference("users");
        UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    userList.add(child.getValue(User.class));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("Error", "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
        SurveyRef = mDatabase.getReference("surveys");
    }
    public void WriteUser(User usr){
        UserRef.child(usr.getUserID()).setValue(usr);
    }
    public void WriteSurvey(Survey survey){SurveyRef.push().setValue(survey);}
    public User getUserFromID(String id){
        for(User usr: userList){
            if(usr.getUserID().equals(id))
                return usr;
    }
        return null;
}
}
```

I think, I can take additional information about users from userList in DatabaseTalk but userList is null always.

**EDIT**
I changed getUserFromID method. OnDataChange() does not work when I called getUserFromID method.

```
public User getUserFromID(String id){
        DatabaseReference newRef = mDatabase.getReference("users");
        DatabaseReference ds = newRef.child(id);
        ds.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return  userList.get(0);
    }
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to show your database structure and the code that isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: Please add your database strucuture.

Comment: If you use ValueEventListeners, you can get the information. It works if there aren't updates too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. It turned out I do not know how Firebase works actually. Since onDataChange() make async calls, writing Listener definitions on a function is useless because onDataChange mostly does not trigger before function terminates and this cause function to return null value.
I make the definition of ValueEventListeners in onCreate methods. It triggers now after few seconds my ProfileFragment created. I think it is better to use Progress Dialogs to wait.

Thanks to everyone who interested in the question.